# SQL Query for below

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where one field in database is like

```
select distinct workorder_ref,workorder_tag from repository.tblworkorder a
where  REGEXP_LIKE (workorder_tag,'^20130912');
```

it gives me output like,

```
workorder_ref   workorder_tag
AJYAMOI         20130912-050226
AJYAXDX         20130912-085750
AJYAXEC         20130912-085753
AJYBLGT         20130912-102759
```

But as you all can see in the query I have hardcoded the date yyyymmdd format (20130912) in example.
So is there any way to go about it ? i was thinking something like below but it does not help.

```
select distinct workorder_ref from repository.tblworkorder a where REGEXP_LIKE
(workorder_tag,'((to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))%)');
```

Comment: Please tag the question with the RDBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc.) you are using.

Comment: You don't need a regexp for this, just a simple LIKE predicate. If you insist on using regular expressions, you may want to read up on their syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this condition:

```
where workorder_tag like to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd') || '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You've enclosed  to_char() within quotes `'....'`, making it a string: `'((to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))%)'`. You need to place the quotes properly.

Also when using REGEXP_LIKE()  you must use `.*` instead of `%`, because it performs regular expression matching instead of the simple `%` pattern matching performed by LIKE.

Corrected version:

```
select distinct workorder_ref from repository.tblworkorder a 
 where REGEXP_LIKE(workorder_tag, to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') || '.*');
```

But in your simple case you can just use LIKE:

```
select distinct workorder_ref from repository.tblworkorder a 
where workorder_tag LIKE to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')|| '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

In **SQL Server** I think the function `GETDATE()` should solve your problem.

Or the function `NOW()` in **MySQL**

`SYSDATE` in **Oracle**